# Turn 'Like' to 'Unlike' if button is already liked by user

Tags: django, django-views

I have the 'Like' button working which adds the currently logged in user to database once button is pressed, but the button doesn't turn to 'Unlike'.

If the button is pressed a second time the 'Like' is removed from the database.

So the key issue is getting the button to change.

I'm thinking I would need a variable for liked_status some where possibly? But wouldn't know how to implement this.

**Views**

```
def BlogLike (request, slug):
    post_id = request.POST.get('blog-id')
    post = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=post_id)
    
    liked = False

    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('viewblog', args=[post_id]))
```

**html**

```
<form action="{% url 'likepost' blog.slug %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if blog.liked is True %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded-0 custom-button" id="like" type="sumbit" name="blog-id" value="{{ blog.slug }}">Unlike<i class="fa-solid fa-heart-crack"></i></button> - {{ blog.total_likes }} Likes
    {% else %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded-0 custom-button" id="like" type="sumbit" name="blog-id" value="{{ blog.slug }}">Like<i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></button> - {{ blog.total_likes }} Likes
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

**view.py**

```
@login_required  
def BlogLike(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    liked = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
            liked = False
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)
            liked = True

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('viewblog', args=[post.slug]))
```

and in **html**

```
{% csrf_token %}
<form action="{% url 'likepost' post.slug %}" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" id="like" value="{{ post.slug }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded-0 custom-button">
    {% if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists %}
      Unlike <i class="fa-solid fa-heart-crack"></i>
    {% else %}
      Like <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
    {% endif %}
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: {% if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists %} returns error

Comment: I edited the answer , show me the error and your model if not work

Comment: Your answer worked but with the url in the html set to:   <form action="{% url 'likepost' post.slug %}" method="POST">

Comment: It's not correct you need to change what I said